# Get AuthenticationProperties in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 RC1 how do I retrieve `AuthenticationProperties` from within a controller or from a filter? `HttpContext.Authentication` does't seem to have this functionality.

I thought about registering an `CookieAuthenticationEvents.OnValidatePrincipal` handler and then using the `Properties` property on the `CookieValidatePrincipalContext` argument. Then I could store those `AuthenticationProperties` in the request cache so that later I'm able to get things like `IssuedUtc`.

Is there a better solution where I don't need to store this myself?

I'm not using ASP.NET Identity but the cookie middleware as standalone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AuthenticationProperties` can be accessed via `IAuthenticateResultFeature`. It's set in AuthN and AuthZ middleware.

```cs
HttpContext.Features.Get<IAuthenticateResultFeature>().AuthenticateResult.Properties
```

Answer (score 8):

In ASP.NET 5, retrieving the authentication properties is a bit cumbersome as it must be done by instantiating an `AuthenticateContext`:

```
var context = new AuthenticateContext("[your authentication scheme]");
await HttpContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(context);

if (context.Principal == null || context.Properties == null) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("The request is not authenticated.");
}

var properties = new AuthenticationProperties(context.Properties);
```

Comment: Does this have any side effects (AuthenticateAsync seems scary)? Can I do this multiple times during a request? Any performance drawbacks?

Comment: No side effect, though that's not a guarantee (as you're totally free to implement your own handler and add your custom logic). You can of course call it multiple times. The impact should be barely noticeable, as the default authentication handlers (like the cookies middleware) return cached results: subsequent `AuthenticateAsync` calls should thus be extremely fast.

Comment: In .Net Core 2 it becomes a little shorter when you avoid the deprecated Authentication class. Replace the first two lines with var context = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("[your authentication scheme]");