# Getting URL parameter while using social login in ASP.NET Core app

Tags: asp.net, facebook, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using social media logins in my ASP.NET Core app. The whole app except for a few pages, requires users to be authenticated.

I have a landing page that allows anonymous users and does a redirect to the login page and it adds a URL parameter i.e. myapp.com/login?id=someid12345

I have three actions in my controller that allow users to login using their social media accounts. The first is just the basic page that renders login buttons. In this first step, I can capture the Id pretty easily.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Login([FromQuery] string id)
{
   // So I can capture the Id here 
}
```

Once the user clicks the social media login of his choice, we come to this action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl, string myId)
{
   var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
   {
      RedirectUri = "Login/Callback"
   };

    // Add returnUrl to properties -- if applicable
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
       properties.Items.Add("returnUrl", returnUrl);

    // Add url param Id to properties -- if applicable
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myId))
       properties.Items.Add("myId", myId);

     await HttpContext.Authentication.ChallengeAsync(provider, properties);

     return;
}
```

My question is, how do I get my Id in the callback action?

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
{
   // I can get user info here once authenticated by social media provider
   var user = HttpContext.User;

   // How do I get myId?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use state parameter for this purpose. State parameter helps to avoid CSRF attacks in OAuth workflow. The state parameter according to the Google OAuth 2.0 docs - Provides any state that might be useful to your application upon receipt of the response. The Google Authorization Server round-trips this parameter, so your application receives the same value it sent. Possible uses include redirecting the user to the correct resource in your site, and cross-site-request-forgery mitigations - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent. This should work in Facebook as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The answer I was looking for is in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534892/get-authenticationproperties-in-asp-net-5